# How to Reverse Engineer Code First for a VB .net project using the Entity Framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, code-first

I have managed this using the following steps

1. Create a new C# project
2. Use the Entity Framework Power Tools to create the models and Mapping in that project from the database
3. Upload the files to http://converter.telerik.com/batch.aspx to convert them to VB .NET
4. Download the VB files
5. Add the VB files to the VB .NET project I am working on
6. Fix any errors caused by the conversion

Does anyone know of a simpler way to do this?

**Edit**
If there isn't another way, I could write my data access layer in a separate C# assembly which would work around the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) is for C# only.

However, it is meant to give you a quick start in code-first projects. Once you reverse-engineered your POCO's you can proceed the code-first way, i.e. modify the class model and use migrations to modify the database. So I think it's not a big point to do this the way you do. You're probably not going to do it too often.